# How to detect disconnects?

Tags: python, stl

I have a piece of code that placed a bunch of primatives in a scene, joins them, and then removes overlap. After this I export them as an stl file, but I’m running into an error where sometimes shapes are just missing (I’m doing this with loads of different shape combinations and extremely repetitively). I think this is due to some weird quirks due to how I’m running blender and I want to implement a fix that detects if there are two disconnected primatives (or two or more groups of primatives) and then returns a true or false depending on any disconnects. I’ve done some
Googling but I haven’t found a solution that works for this workflow. Does anyone have any helpful tips?